# Array pointers giving Garbage value while looping through it

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am a CPP noob. Sometime (only sometime) I get garbage value for the zeroth index of the array which is passing to a display function as array pointer.
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void display(int arr[], int size)
{
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }
}


int main()
{
    int size = 8;
    int arr [size] = {6, 3, 1, 0, 2, 9, 8, 7};
    int temp;
    int j;

    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        j = i+1;
        while (j!=0 && arr[j] < arr[j-1])
        {
            temp = arr[j-1];
            arr[j-1] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
            j--;
        }
    }
    display(arr, size);
}
```

And here is my output of one instance. Sometime I get the proper value which makes it difficult to debug.

```
-1200926128
0
1
2
3
6
7
8
[Finished in 0.3s]
```

Comment: This `int arr [size]` is not legal C++. The size must be a compile time constant.

Comment: good time to get used to the debugger

Comment: On the last iteration, `i == size-1` and `j==size`, whereupon `arr[j]` exhibits undefined behavior by way of a buffer overrun.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, That make sense. Let me try it out please

Comment: @NeilButterworth, Thanks for that comment Neil. So I should pass the number itself?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, You were absolutely correct. That worked. How can I mark your's as answer?

Comment: @hhsecond you pester him to make an answer instead of answering in comments :p

Answer (score 0):

you can not use "variables" while giving array size. It can be const.

your problem is in your logic.

Hints : Add cout statement in your logic and debug your code yourself :P :)

```
        while (j!=0 && arr[j] < arr[j-1])
        {
            temp = arr[j-1];
            arr[j-1] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
            cout << "arr["<<j<<"] is "<< arr[j]<<endl;
            cout<< "arr[" << j-1<< "is " << arr[j-1]<<endl; 
           j--;
```

use cout statements, and you would be able to debug further :).